# Can't get rid of 'no rule to process file' warnings and 'duplicate output file' errors in framework upon pod linting

Tags: swift, cocoapods

#### Problem

Pod lib lint passes with warnings about "no rules to process files" in the .xcodeproj/ folder of my framework.

Pod spec lint fails with the same warnings as above except also for MyLib/build. I don't have a MyLib/build folder in my repository. It also gives me 2 errors having to do with derived data.

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-efnsaqjhuzmwkkftkwknbhzigxxe/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MaterialFields/MaterialFields.framework/Headers/MaterialFields.h':
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-efnsaqjhuzmwkkftkwknbhzigxxe/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MaterialFields/MaterialFields.framework/Headers/MaterialFields-Swift.h':
```

#### What I've Tried

I've tried everything from deleting my derived data, erasing all my simulator content, cloning my repo into a different location and trying the commands again. I've checked my build phases for duplicate files. Nothing has worked.

I've opened up an issue on the cocoa pods GitHub (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8772). One of the contributors was kind enough to clone it and run it and it passed just fine (with the same 6 no rules to process warnings for stuff inside the .xcodeproj package).

#### My Thoughts

I'm expecting the linter to pass as it does locally. I have a feeling it has something to do with the MyLib/build file that gets created for the pod spec lint which gives me a lot of warnings. Likewise, I don't know how to fix the DerivedData error. I can't find any information to help me out online.

What files should I be excluding in my podspec? So far I'm only excluding the plist.